# Apache-Zeppelin / Spark : Why can't I access a remote DB with this code sample

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scalar, apache-zeppelin

I am doing my first own steps with Spark and Zeppelin and don't understand why this code sample isn't working.

First Block:

```
%dep
z.reset()                                                     // clean up 
z.load("/data/extraJarFiles/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar")         // load a jdbc driver for postgresql
```

Second Block

```
%spark
// This code loads some data from a PostGreSql DB with the help of a JDBC driver.
// The JDBC driver is stored on the Zeppelin server, the necessary Code is transfered to the Spark Workers and the workers build the connection with the DB.
// 
// The connection between table and data source is "lazy".  So the data will only be loaded in the case that an action need them.
// With the current script means this the DB is queried twice.   ==> Q:  How can I keep a RDD in Mem or on disk?

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet

import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.222.22.222:5432/myDatabase"
val username = "postgres"
val pw = "geheim"

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance                             // activating the jdbc driver. The jar file was loaded inside of the %dep block


case class RowClass(Id:Integer, Col1:String , Col2:String)                         // create a class with possible values

val myRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc,                                                    // SparkContext sc
                        () => DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pw),    // scala.Function0<java.sql.Connection> getConnection
                        "select * from tab1 where \"Id\">=? and \"Id\" <=? ",  // String sql    Important: we need here two '?' for the lower/upper Bounds vlaues
                        0,                                                     // long lowerBound   = start value
                        10000,                                                // long upperBound,  = end value that is still included
                        1,                                                     // int numPartitions  = the area is spitted into x sub commands.   
                                                                               //  e.g. 0,1000,2  => first cmd from 0 ... 499, second cmd from 500..1000
                        row => RowClass(row.getInt("Id"),
                                        row.getString("Col1"),
                                        row.getString("Col2"))
                       )

myRDD.toDF().registerTempTable("Tab1")

// --- improved methode (not working at the moment)----
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("user",username)
prop.setProperty("password",pw)

val tab1b = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"tab1",prop)             // <-- not working

tab1b.show
```

So what is the problem.

I want to connect to an external PostgreSql DB.

Block I is adding the necessary JAR file for the DB and first lines of the second block is already using the JAR and it is able get some data out of the DB.

But the first way is ugly, because you have to convert the data by your own into a table, so I want to use the easier method at the end of the script.

But I am getting the error message

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:postgresql://10.222.22.222:5432/myDatabase

But it is the same URL / same login / same PW  from the above code.
Why is this not working?

Maybe somebody has a helpful hint for me.

---- Update: 24.3. 12:15 ---

I don't think the loading of the JAR is not working. I added an extra `val db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pw);` for testing. (The function that fails inside of the Exception)  And this works well.

Another interesting detail.  If I remove the %dep block and class line, produces the first block a very similar error.   Same Error Message; same function + line number that is failing, but the stack of functions is a bit different.

I have found the source code here:   http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java

My problem is in line 689.    So if all parameters are OK , maybe it comes from the `isDriverAllowed()` check ?

Comment: The problem you got is that Zeppelin has not loaded the jdbc driver for Postgres. What version of zeppelin do you use?

Comment: I am using "zeppelin-0.5.6".
But why is the first block able to access the DB and the second one isn't working?    
This feels like the `z.load()` function adds the jdbc to a list that is search from the `JdbcRDD()` function and is ignored from the `sqlContext.read.jdbc()` function.

Comment: Could you try doing the followin: in your interpreter configuration, add the following property: `spark.driver.extraClassPath` with the value `/data/extraJarFiles/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar` . You could access the interpreter configuration on clicking on the top banner of Zeppelin -->  Interpretter

Comment: This extra line just end in a new error msg.
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Found both spark.driver.extraClassPath and SPARK_CLASSPATH. Use only the former.`
I don't set this value anywhere, but found SPARK_CLASSPATH inside of the logs, so it must be part of the starting process.
I added a few more details to the first post.

Comment: Check the spark-env.sh and zeppelin-env.sh and comment the SPARK_CLASSPATH line

Comment: I ve just read your edits. Actually that's exactly what I wanted to know, I have had some doubts that the dependecies are not injected in the SparkContext. I ve experienced already the same problem, and i resolved it in zeppelin-env.sh: by adding the line: `export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--jars /data/extraJarFiles/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar` and restart Zeppelin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve had the same problem with dependencies in Zeppelin, and I had to add my jars to the SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS in zeepelin-env.sh to have them included in all notebooks and paragraphs

SO in zeppelin-env.sh you modify SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS to be:

`export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--jars /data/extraJarFiles/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar`

Then you have to restart your zeppelin instance.

Comment: can you put your solution? what do you mean by " Zeppelin can communicate with spark or can do all the work in a standalone mode by its own" ?

Comment: This wasn't the correct answer for my case, but it has lead me to the solution.
Zeppelin can communicate with spark or can do all the work in a standalone mode by its own.
The parameter SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS is only used in combination with Spark. 
My small test environment is runing in standalone mode, so it was ignoring the parameter. 
But with the hint that Zeppeelin is calling other programs could I trace this with a simple `ps -efH` command.
Zeppelin is executing interpreter.sh and this is calling Java again.
So I moved my JAR file into a folder from the used class path and all is working.

Comment: Exactly... Th interpreter process which is, for a spark interpreter, a spark process. It is like you are doing spark-shell.

Comment: About the question:  
You can install Zeppelin without any extra software ( no Spark / no Hadoop).   So you just download the software and unzip it into a folder and it is already working. So you can do with this setup already your first tests with the integrated Spark interpreter.  But it looks like the system behaves a bit different compared with a full setup. e.g. The parameter from the %dep block are not submitted to the sub java process.    The code inside of interpreter.sh is showing the different ways.

Answer (score 0):

In my case while executing a spark/scala code, I received the same error. I had previously set SPARK_CLASSPATH in my spark-env.sh conf file - it was pointing to a jar file. I removed/commented out the line in spark-env.sh and restarted zepplin. This got rid of the error.